# Find the generators of multiplicative group of units efficiently?

Tags: finite-field, group-theory

Say you're give some prime numbers $p_{1},p_{2},p_{3}, p = 2p_{1}p_{2}p_{3} + 1$ (which is assumed to be also prime) and a list of numbers $L$ and you're asked to find the generators of the multiplicative group of units of $Z_p$.

What would be an efficient way to do so?

This question comes from a cryptography course so that the prime numbers are really big and also the list of numbers is formed by big numbers so that I'm having trouble to apply [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814879/find-a-generator-of-the-multiplicative-group-of-mathbbz-23-mathbbz-as-a-c) kind of method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For any $g$ in the set $\mathbb Z_p^*=\{1,2,\dots,p-1\}$, consider the function $F_g$ over that set defined by $F_g(x)\;=\;g\cdot x\bmod p$. Since $p$ is prime, by [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), iterating $F_g$, starting from $1$, $p-1$ times, cycles back to $1$.

By definition, $g$ is a generator of $\mathbb Z_p^*$ if and only if that cycling does not occur before these $p-1$ iterations. The smallest $k>0$ where the cycling occurs divides $p-1$ (that $k$ is the order of $g$). Proof sketch: if that $k$ did not divide $p-1$, $k'=(p-1)\bmod k$ would be a smaller $k'>0$ for which the cycling occurs.

It follows that we can test if some $g$ not divisible by $p$ is a generator of $\mathbb Z_p^*$ by checking if $g^k\bmod p\ne1$, with $k=(p-1)/q$ for $q$ each of the distinct prime factors of $p-1$.

Here, for $g$ each of the integers in list $L$, we check if $g\bmod p\ne0$, and $g^{(p-1)/2}\bmod p\ne1$, and $g^{(p-1)/p_1}\bmod p\ne1$, and $g^{(p-1)/p_2}\bmod p\ne1$, and $g^{(p-1)/p_3}\bmod p\ne1$. In the affirmative, and only then, $g$ is a generator of $\mathbb Z_p^*$.

Additions:

- Computing $g^k\bmod p$ is feasible with a modest computer, and common, for integers of many thousands of bits: $2\log_2(k)$ modular multiplications are enough to compute $g^k\bmod p$; see [modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).
- If the list $L$ was not a given, we could try $g$ at random (or small primes by increasing orders, which is slightly more efficient than trying small integers by increasing order). If all the primes dividing $(p-1)/2$ are large (which is the case here), nearly 50% of candidates will work, thus a search won't be too long.
- Often, we want a generator of a subgroup of order one of the large primes dividing $p-1$, say $p_3$; we can get that as $g'=g^{(p-1)/p_3}\bmod p$.

Comment: For a detailed proof of the "It follows that we can test…" assertion, see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/102301/555)

Answer (score 4):

Even for the simple case of primitive roots, there is no know general algorithm for [finding a generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots) except trying all candidates (from the list).

If the prime factorization of the Carmichael function $\lambda(n)\;$ or 
the Euler totient $\varphi(n)\;$ is known, there are effective algorithms
for computing  the order of a group element,
see e.g. Algorithm 1.4.3 in H. Cohen's book *A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory*. A better available source maybe **Algorithm 4.79: Determining the order of a group element** from *Applied Cryptography*  by A.J. Menezes et al. (you can download a pdf of ch. 4 from http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/).

In your case for **prime** $ p = 2p_{1}p_{2}p_{3} + 1$ you have the easy 
complete factorization 
$$\varphi(p)=p-1=2p_{1}p_{2}p_{3}$$

Answer (score 3):

**fgrieu**'s answer in algorithmic shape:

Given is prime $p$ and multiplicative group $(\Bbb Z_p^*, \cdot)$.

1.) Find all prime factors $\{p_1,p_2,...,p_k\}$ of $p-1$.

2.) Iterate through $g = 2,3,... $ until a generator is found,

where $g$ is a generator of $(\Bbb Z_p^*, \cdot)$, iff

\begin{equation}\forall i\in\{1,...,k\}: g^\frac{p-1}{p_i}\neq 1 \mod p \end{equation}

Step 2.) terminates due to existence of the generator.