# Generators and Multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z_7}$

Tags: group-theory

In the [multiplication table](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Z_7) for $\mathbb{Z^*_7}$, each row has all the elements of the set

My questions are:

> 1. is each element a generator here? if not why?
> 2. is an element considered as generator only if $Order(G) = Order(g)$ i.e $Order(g) = 6$  hence $g=3$ is a generator.
> 3. is there any formula to find the number of generators?
> 4. Some website says phi(n) gives the order of group some says $\varphi(n)$ gives the number of generators some says $\varphi(n)$ gives the number of elements with a multiplicative inverse. Which of these is correct?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. is each element a generator here? if not why?

Take the $2$ and calculate $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \equiv 8 \equiv 1 \mod7$. Therefore, not every element is a generator.

> 2. is an element considered as generator only if $Order(G) = Order(g)$ i.e $Order(g) = 6$  hence $g=3$ is a generator.

A generator must generate all the element. If the order of $Order(a) = x < g = Order(G)$ then it cannot generates all the elements. $a^x =1 $ and the cyclic sub-group generated by $x$ contains only $x$ elements:

$$a^1,a^2, \ldots, a^x = 1$$

> 3. is there any formula to find the number of generators?

No, there is [no formula](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/40654/18298).

> 4. Some website says $\varphi(n)$ gives the order of group some says $\varphi(n)$ gives the number of generators some says $\varphi(n)$ gives the number of elements with a multiplicative inverse. Which of these is correct?

Remember the $\mathbb{Z_7}$ is a field.

- $\varphi(n)$ gives the [order of the multiplicative group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n). In your case $\varphi(7) = 7-1 = 6$
- 2 and 4 are not generators therefore $\varphi(n)$ cannot give the number of generators.
- Being a field implies every element is invertible, thus  $\varphi(7)$ gives the number of invertible elements, also for the composite case $-\mathbb{Z_n}-$, where $n$ is a composite number,  $\varphi(n)$,  gives the number of invertible elements.

Comment: Take the 2 and calculate 2⋅2⋅2≡8≡1mod7. Therefore, not every element is a generator , could you explain this . why are we checking mod 7 of 8 ?

Comment: if you had checked the table i posted , it can be observed that each row recreates the elements of z7 , then why isnt each element not considered as a generator

Comment: Because we are talking about $\mathbb{Z_7}$. Each row contains distinct numbers since if there are more then one for a number say $a$ and $x$ is multiple times occurs then $x = a \cdot b= a \cdot c \Rightarrow  b = c$.