# Finding generator element for multiplicative group of order $n$ - feasible?

Tags: rsa, cryptanalysis, modular-arithmetic

Given a multiplicative group of order $n$, how hard is it to find a generator element (such that all other elements can be expressed as powers of that generator)?

What would be the complexity?

Comment: This might be helpful [Find the generators of multiplicative group of units efficiently?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40654/find-the-generators-of-multiplicative-group-of-units-efficiently)

Comment: @caffein Since this is tagged "RSA": Are you really interested in a group $G$ of *order* $n$, or did you mean the multiplicative group $(\mathbb Z/n)^\ast$ of invertible elements *modulo* $n$ (which never has order $n$)?

Comment: What does _multiplicative_ mean, beside notation? How exactly are we given the group? Are we given $n$? The neutral? A way to generate other elements in the group? A way to apply the group law on previously given/obtained elements? A way to test equality of elements obtained? Can we obtain the factorization of $n$? As noted above, the tag RSA seems wrong.

Comment: Hints: How does knowing the factorization of $n$ help test if an element $g$ is a generator? What is the proportion of generators in the group? What plausible hypothesis in addition to those in my previous comment do we need to obtain an heuristic algorithm yielding a generator ? Note: that algorithm is often used in practice.